# consteval function returning object with non-trivial constexpr destructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

C++20 will have the new [consteval](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r3.html) keyword and [constexpr destructor](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0784r7.html) if all goes well.
Sadly no compiler that I know of implements [consteval](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r3.html) at this time.
Will the following code be valid?

```
struct A {
  constexpr ~A() {}
};

consteval A f() {
    return A{};
}

void test() {
    A a;
    a = f(); // <-- here
}
```

The issue comes from the line I marked — the destructor of the temporary `A` returned by `f` need to be called. but it should be called at the end of the full expression. so outside of the immediate evaluation.

I didn't find any quotes from the [consteval](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r3.html) and [constexpr destructor](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0784r7.html) papers that explicitly forbid this, but I can't see how it could be correct.

Will the following code be valid in C++20?
What should happen with this code?

---

Note:

In the [consteval paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r3.html), this example is given. Here the consteval function is called outside of constant context.

```
consteval int sqr(int n) {
  return n*n;
}
constexpr int r = sqr(100);  // Okay.
int x = 100;
int r2 = sqr(x);  // Error: Call does not produce a constant.
```

Comment: from my understanding of consteval it is not the case the call will be folded at complie-time. but the assignement to a of the constant resulting of f will be assigned at run time.

Comment: Regarding you edit with, *here the consteval function is called outside of constant context.*,  Why do you think it is not considered a constant context?  Also, did you see the `constexpr int dblsqr(int n) {
  return 2*sqr(n); // Error: Enclosing function is not
}                  // consteval.` part?

Comment: i think the issue with the `constexpr int dblsqr(int n) { return 2*sqr(n); // Error: Enclosing function is not } // consteval.` is that the argument given to the consteval function is not known at compile-time or may not be.

Comment: Exactly.  It's not a constant expression so it can't be called.

Comment: the argument not being a constant expression and the call being outside of constant context are two different things.

Comment: Do'h.  That's correct.  Got my thinking backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code is fine.

The salient aspect of `consteval` is [[expr.const]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#12):

> An expression or conversion is in an *immediate function context* if it is potentially evaluated and its innermost non-block scope is a function parameter scope of an immediate function. An expression or conversion is an *immediate invocation* if it is an explicit or implicit invocation of an immediate function and is not in an immediate function context. An immediate invocation shall be a constant expression.

In

```
void test() {
    A a;
    a = f(); // <-- here
}
```

`f()` is an *immediate invocation* (it is an explicit invocation of an immediate function that is not in an immediate function context). So the requirement is that `f()` has to be a constant expression.

Note: just `f()`, not `a = f();`, there is no requirement that the assignment operator here is a constant expression.

Everything that `f()` invokes is perfectly fine. All of `A`'s special member functions are invocable during constant evaluation time. The result of `f()` is a permitted result of a constant expression ([[expr.const]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#10)) likewise because it does not trigger any of the restrictions there either (`A` has no pointer or reference members, so trivially none of them refer to objects without static storage duration).

Ultimately, the question of constant evaluation boils down to going through all the list of restrictions and seeing if anything breaks. I don't think we violate any of the rules, so this should be fine.

Comment: so the destructor of the value returned by f will not be called or called at runtime on a constant computed at complie-time ?

Comment: @Tyker Yes, it will be called at runtime. The temporary is materialized, and then needs to be destroyed.

Comment: Ok weird but ok.

Comment: [an immediate invocation is a full expr](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5) and [all side-effects of a full expression are resolved during the full expr](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#9) so how can de destructor of the value returned by `f` be executed outside of an immediate invocation ?

Comment: @Tyker We have to call an `A::operator=()` at runtime, assigning from an object that needs to not have been destroyed yet.

Comment: The materialization of the temporary, and its subsequent destruction, is not part of the immediate invocation.

Comment: i understand that we can't destroy the object while we still need it. but destroying the object after the assignment mean that the side-effect(destruction of the return value) of an full expression([immediate invocations are full expression](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5)) is computed after the end of the full expression. which seem to contradict http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#9

Comment: @TC so destruction of temporaries are not considered to be side-effects until the temporary is materialized ?